# Large HTTP header with Ktor

Tags: ktor

Our Ktor application clients are sending headers larger than 8KB. Those requests are being rejected by KTor server engines with a HTTP 400. I've tried Netty and Tomcat so far and they both fail with a HTTP 400 status. With Tomcat engine, the error is more obvious as the response from Tomcat contains the text: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large` . I have tried the configuration suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-27 . The config parameter `maxHeaderLength` doesn't work. This was suggested in the related PR https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/pull/2490 . I am using Ktor version 1.6.8. How can I get my Ktor apps working with large headers, like headers with almost 16000 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the Netty engine to provide a `HttpServerCodec` object with  the desired value for maximum header size. Here is an example:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, applicationEngineEnvironment {
    connector {
        port = 3333
    }

    module {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText { "Hello" }
            }
        }
    }
}) {
    httpServerCodec = {
        HttpServerCodec(
            HttpObjectDecoder.DEFAULT_MAX_INITIAL_LINE_LENGTH,
            32 * 1024, // max header size
            HttpObjectDecoder.DEFAULT_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE
        )
    }
}.start(true)
```

Comment: Can this be done through a conf file? We currently have this `fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)` and the configuration in `application.conf' file.  Similar to https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/2.0.3/codeSnippets/snippets/engine-main/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt

Comment: No. Only through a code.

Answer (score 0):

It also can be configured in `application.conf`, such as:

```
ktor {
  deployment {
    maxInitialLineLength = 2048
    maxHeaderSize = 1024
    maxChunkSize = 42
  }
}
```

See docs: https://ktor.io/docs/engines.html#netty-file